# Regular representation, two viewpoints, the isomorphism

Tags: representation-theory, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a group. Let $G^* = \{\phi: G\to \mathbb{C}\}$ be the complex functions defined on $G$.

We have the representations

$$\rho: G \to GL(G^*), \space \rho(g) = \phi \mapsto (h\mapsto \phi(hg))$$

$$\psi : G \to GL(\mathbb{C}^{|G|}), \space \psi(g) = e_h \mapsto e_{gh}$$

right? (The latter is defined on the (standard) basis elements $e_h, h\in G$ and extended linearly).

I want to show that the linear isomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{C}^{|G|} \to G^*$ that takes $e_h \mapsto \chi_{h}$ (characteristic function of $h$) is an isomorphism between the representations $\rho$ and $\psi$.

For this we must show that for a $e_h, h\in G$

$$\varphi(\psi(g) e_h) = \rho(g)(\varphi(e_h))$$

But
$$\varphi(\psi(g) e_h) = \varphi(e_{gh}) = \chi_{gh}$$

and

$$\rho(g)(\varphi(e_h)) = \rho(g)\chi_h =  \rho(g) (z\mapsto\chi_h(z)) = z\mapsto\chi_h(zg) = \chi_{hg^{-1}}$$

Where am I in the wrong?

PS.
It takes me hours of pain in the neck to do these and usually they end up wrong like this. Each time I start from the beginning and do them mechanically with absolutely no understanding or routine. How to also achieve those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

**Option 1:**
Define $\rho(g)$ by $\phi\mapsto (h\mapsto \phi(g^{-1}h))$. Then,
$$
[\rho(g).\chi_h](x)=\chi_h(g^{-1}x)=\begin{cases}1&\mbox g^{-1}x=h\\0&\mbox{else.}\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, $\rho(g).\chi_h=\chi_{gh}$ (since $g^{-1}x=h \iff x=gh$). Now,
$$
\rho(g).\varphi(e_h)=\rho(g).\chi_h=\chi_{gh}=\varphi(e_{gh})=\varphi(\psi(g).e_h)
$$
as desired.

**Option 2:**
Define $\varphi(e_h)=\chi_{h^{-1}}$. Then,
$$
\rho(g).\chi_h=\chi_{hg^{-1}}
$$
as you observed above. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\rho(g).\phi(e_h)&=\rho(g).\chi_{h^{-1}}\\
&=\chi_{h^{-1}g^{-1}}\\
&=\chi_{(gh)^{-1}}\\
&=\varphi(e_{gh})\\
&=\varphi(\psi(g).e_h).
\end{align}